# youtube iframe player doesn't automatically switch quality in low bandwidth on mobile

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, youtube-api

Using iOS 9.3, link conditioning set to 3g speed, loading a video in the youtube iframe api in safari.

I would expect the iframe api to realize that it has been buffering a bunch and try to get a lower quality stream to keep the video playback smooth, like it does in the native youtube app.

Am I missing something obvious? I basically copied and pasted out of the youtube ios helper wrapper but it still tries to play in a quality that is too high for the connection speed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    body { margin: 0; width:100%; height:100%;  background-color:#000000; }
    html { width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#000000; }

    .embed-container iframe,
    .embed-container object,
    .embed-container embed {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="embed-container">
        <div id="player"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api" onerror="window.location.href='ytplayer://onYouTubeIframeAPIFailedToLoad'"></script>
    <script>
    var player;
    var error = false;

    YT.ready(function() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
  "events" : {
    "onPlaybackQualityChange" : "onPlaybackQualityChange",
    "onReady" : "onReady",
    "onError" : "onPlayerError",
    "onStateChange" : "onStateChange"
  },
  "width" : "100%",
  "height" : "100%",
  "videoId" : 'NP7nK2zPirc',
  "playerVars" : {
    "showinfo" : 0,
    "modestbranding" : 1,
    "autohide" : 1,
    "playsinline" : 1,
    "controls" : 0
  }
});
        player.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onYouTubeIframeAPIReady';

        // this will transmit playTime frequently while playng
        function getCurrentTime() {
             var state = player.getPlayerState();
             if (state == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                 time = player.getCurrentTime()
                 // window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onPlayTime?data=' + time;
             }
        }

        window.setInterval(getCurrentTime, 500);

    });

    function onReady(event) {
        // window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onReady?data=' + event.data;
    }

    function onStateChange(event) {
        if (!error) {            
            // window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onStateChange?data=' + event.data;
        }
        else {
            error = false;
        }
    }

    function onPlaybackQualityChange(event) {
        // window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onPlaybackQualityChange?data=' + event.data;
    }

    function onPlayerError(event) {
        if (event.data == 100) {
            error = true;
        }
        // window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onError?data=' + event.data;
    }

    window.onresize = function() {
        player.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_quality), if the playback quality changes, the [`onPlaybackQualityChange`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#onPlaybackQualityChange) event will fire, and your code should respond to the event rather than the fact that it called the `setPlaybackQuality` function.

> [`onPlaybackQualityChange`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#onPlaybackQualityChange) event fires whenever the video playback quality changes. For example, if you call the [`setPlaybackQuality(suggestedQuality)`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#setPlaybackQuality) function, this event will fire if the playback quality actually changes. Your application should respond to the event and should not assume that the quality will automatically change when the [`setPlaybackQuality(suggestedQuality)`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#setPlaybackQuality) function is called. Similarly, your code should not assume that playback quality will only change as a result of an explicit call to setPlaybackQuality or any other function that allows you to set a suggested playback quality.

Then I recommend calling the `getAvailableQualityLevels()` function to determine which quality levels are available for a video. For example, if your page displays a 1280px by 720px video player, a `hd720` quality video will actually look better than an `hd1080` quality video.

Check these related SO threads:

- [YouTube iFrame API "setPlaybackQuality" or "suggestedQuality" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802498/youtube-iframe-api-setplaybackquality-or-suggestedquality-not-working)

> If you use event 3 (buffering) instead of event 5 (playing) there's no
>   stutter for the user. Quality is changed as soon as it starts loading.
>   Only weird thing is you need to set it in onPlayerReady as well or it
>   doesn't work.
>
> ```
> function onPlayerReady(event) {
>     event.target.setPlaybackQuality('hd720');
> }
> function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
>     if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) {
>         event.target.setPlaybackQuality('hd720');
>     }
> }
> ```

- [Set jw player youtube video playback quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454090/set-jw-player-youtube-video-playback-quality/30395558#30395558)

Hope this helps!