# setPlaybackQuality not working YouTube JS API

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

First video is loaded in `1080p` than when I press a button with `class="quality"` It should change the quality to 720p but `it's not working in HTML5 player.`

It works on Flash Player but not in HTML5. I'm using JavaScript Player API.

Note: None of these solutions worked for me. YouTube iFrame API "setPlaybackQuality" or "suggestedQuality" not working

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    event.target.setPlaybackQuality('hd1080'); //works
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        $(".quality").click(function() {
            event.target.setPlaybackQuality('hd720'); //doesn't work
        });    
    }
}
```

**The problem is you can not downgrade quality. Once you set to 1080p for ex you can not go back to 720p.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [YouTube iFrame API "setPlaybackQuality" or "suggestedQuality" not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802498/youtube-iframe-api-setplaybackquality-or-suggestedquality-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken the example from this site [**YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).
I have manually added one button to change the quality which is working absolutely fine, Here is the working code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="change_quality">Change Quality</button>
        <div id="player"></div>
        <script>
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
            var player;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
                });
            }
            function onPlayerReady(event) {
                event.target.playVideo();
                event.target.setPlaybackQuality('360p');
            }
            function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                    $("#change_quality").click(function() {
                        event.target.setPlaybackQuality('240p');
                    });
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Initially **onPlayerReady** the quality is set to **360p**.
After clicking on **Change Quality** button the quality is set to 144p.

Comment: The problem is you can not downgrade quality. Once you set to 1080p for ex you can not go back to 720p

See my updated question or set the values hd1080 and then on #change quality button hd720 @Varun

Comment: @rexhin, In my example I am also downgrading the quality from 360p to 144p.

Comment: Yes but it doesen't seem to be working from 1080p to 720p @Varun

Comment: setPlaybackQuality seems to have stopped working around December 2017, at least for me... Am I the only one?

Comment: @FrankEinstein  Any word on this?  I've noticed it's not working for me either.

Comment: It's even not working on their official documentation of the API's.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

Comment: any alternate solution for this? @VarunChakervarti

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping the video, then setting the playback quality, then resuming playback.

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    $(".quality").click(function() {
        event.target.stopVideo();
        event.target.setPlaybackQuality('hd720');
        event.target.playVideo();
    });    
}
```