# YouTube iframe cannot play "tiny" on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm building a web app that plays YouTube videos using iframe API.

The problem I'm trying to solve is on iOS, when the iPhone is under slow cellular network, the YouTube cannot load at all. I realized it also happens on YouTube mobile website with Safari or Chrome (it has no problems with YouTube app tho).

Then I call `getAvailableQualityLevels()` to see the quality the iframe player returns and I see that on iOS it doesn't support `tiny` and a few other options while on Android it does. On Android, with slow cellular it is working as expected with the same video.

iOS: `["hd720", "medium", "small", "auto"]`

Android: `["hd1080", "hd720", "large", "medium", "small", "tiny", "auto"]`

I couldn't find any document mentioning about this. I really need to make it work with cellular network. Any ideas for workarounds?

Comment: This question seems related to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468161/loading-youtube-iframe-api-video-at-a-lower-quality).

Comment: I read that post before and I could use `loadVideoById()` to change the quality. But the issue I'm stating here is the player on iOS does not allow `tiny` for some reasons. I wonder if it is a bug or just a veiled restriction. I hope Google team would answer this issue.

Comment: Which library do you use? I was trying to use YouTube iFrame API + WKWebView but only `medium` quality is available? How did you get `hd720`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029515/can-we-get-normal-quality-of-youtube-video-using-safari-browser-or-wkwebview