# Can we get normal quality of YouTube video using Safari browser or WKWebView?

Tags: ios, youtube, wkwebview

Or good quality is only possible with official YouTube app on iOS?

I was trying to use the next iOS libraries to play YouTube in my app but it always chooses `medium` quality and it can't be changed

https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player

YouTube IFrame API methods don't change anything:

`player.setPlaybackQuality(suggestedQuality:String):Void`

`loadVideoById({'videoId': 'bHQqvYy5KYo', 'suggestedQuality': 'large'});`

Safari browser from iPhone Simulator XR (iOS 12.2):

I'm trying to change quality for a video which definitely has full hd quality but 360p as maximum is only available when I test in Safari app:

[image]

**Update**

Tested on real device (iPhone 6s) - the same problem, only official YouTube app allows to set normal quality.

Chrome Browser also doesn't allow to change quality

**Update 2**

`var qualities = player.getAvailableQualityLevels();` - it returns `medium, auto` for full hd videos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution.

Apple replaces YouTube player with their own everywhere. They limit quality to 360p. Though they remove ads. Good quality is only available in YouTube official app from Google