# Under what circumstances would Youtube setPlaybackQuality function not pick the suggested quality?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Youtube Iframe API says the following"

> player.setPlaybackQuality(suggestedQuality:String):Void This function
>   sets the suggested video quality for the current video. The function
>   causes the video to reload at its current position in the new quality.
>   If the playback quality does change, it will only change for the video
>   being played. Calling this function does not guarantee that the
>   playback quality will actually change. However, if the playback
>   quality does change, the onPlaybackQualityChange event will fire, and
>   your code should respond to the event rather than the fact that it
>   called the setPlaybackQuality function.

I am working with the API and realize that for a video the default quality picked up was "large". Using the API, I am unable to set it to "hd720". Setting to any other quality fails. Also after the quality is set to "hd720", re-setting it to "large" also fails.

So can someone please explain me why this can happen?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Youtube iFrame API setPlaybackQuality ignored on mobile device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562150/youtube-iframe-api-setplaybackquality-ignored-on-mobile-device)

Comment: @JAL: No, I am using it on a desktop browser

Comment: I realized that I can increase the quality, ie. setPlaybackQuality("medium") works if current quality is "small" but not other way around.