# Mobile YouTube in High-definition

Tags: javascript, mobile, youtube, userscripts, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to play a video on the YouTube mobile website (https://m.youtube.com) in 720p or more. So far I am failing.

### My analysis so far

When accessing the mobile website, YouTube doesn't offer controls for the quality setting. I am employing JavaScript to add this functionality. My intention is to later inject that later with a browser extension.

Here are two angles I have tried so far:

**1) using `loadVideoById`**

```
player = document.getElementsByClassName("_msc")[0];
id = player.getVideoData()["video_id"];
player.loadVideoById(id, 0, "hd720");

// debug information
player.getAvailableQualityLevels();  // --> reports ["hd1080", "hd720", "large", "medium", "small", "tiny", "auto"]
player.getPlaybackQuality();
player.showVideoInfo();  // shows statistics below in viewport
```

However, the new player is still in quality `medium`. The script works for setting it to a smaller quality `small` and `tiny`. Often this happens when the viewport is to small. However in our case it is large enough to support a the `large` (`854 x 480`) quality setting, see on the picture below. Still switching to it doesn't work. It only loads up to `medium` (`640 x 360`).

[image]

**2) using `setPlaybackQuality`**

This is the official way of switching the quality, which works perfectly on the desktop version of the website (https://www.youtube.com).

```
player.stopVideo();
player.setPlaybackQuality("large");
player.seekTo(10);
```

Then calling `player.getPlaybackQuality()` still only reports `medium`. Note that this script doesn't work to set it to a smaller value `small`, `tiny`. So it doesn't seem to work at all.

---

On the desktop version both versions work. However to retrieved one has to use: 
`player = document.getElementById('movie_player');`.

Also when testing this on the desktop, accessing the mobile site requires me to to a user agent switch to one of a mobile browser.

### Question

How can I sucessfully change the quality to anything higher than `medium`?

Comment: Other people have failed similarly with the two approaches I have outlined:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562150/youtube-iframe-api-setplaybackquality-ignored-on-mobile-device?rq=1

Comment: Did you find out a solution for it? I also get only `medium` quality: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029515/can-we-get-normal-quality-of-youtube-video-using-safari-browser-or-wkwebview

Comment: No I haven't found solution.

Comment: Yeah, there is no solution. Apple replaces YouTube player everywhere with their own. Limits quality to 360p. Though they remove ads. Good quality only available in YouTube official app from Google