# iOS setPlaybackQuality not work by using the YouTube Helper Library

Tags: ios, youtube, helper

I've tried many solutions, like [YouTube iFrame API "setPlaybackQuality" or "suggestedQuality" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802498/youtube-iframe-api-setplaybackquality-or-suggestedquality-not-working).
But it doesn't work now. I've updated the helper library to date, too. Was setPlaybackQuality() no longer supported on mobile device (like iPhone)? How does iPhone change youtube video quality now?
Thanks.

EDIT:
2015-01-21
1. I tried to invoke player.loadVideoById:startSecond:suggestQuality with hd720 during PLAYING state. But it still turns to medium quality.
2. I tried to invoke player.setSize(1280,720), it did change quality to hd720! But video visible area is out of current player view bound (e.g. 320x180).

Any solution is welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution? I've created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55994629/cannot-change-youtube-video-quality-at-all-always-starts-with-medium-with-io

Comment: for me even `player.setSize(1280,720);` doesn't work on iOS 12. Did it work for you before? What about now (with iOS 12)?