# Why onClick next video function, using the YouTube JavaScript Player API, the quality drop down to default?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, youtube-api

I'm on CodeIgniter and I have this issue, using the next_video API function, onClick of the button the new video has a low quality than previous, so basically the first video is always at my suggestion quality and next always at default quality.

On my `template` I have this `div`:

```
 <div id="ytapiplayer">
    You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
  </div>
```

This is my `custom.js`:

```
function loadNewVideo(id, startSeconds,quality,ads) {

    console.log(ytplayer);
  if (ytplayer) {

     $("#current progress-bar").width("0%");   
     if(ads != '')  
     {
        tempVideo   = id;
        id          = ads;
        console.log(ads);
     }
    ytplayer.loadVideoById(id, parseInt(startSeconds),'hd720');

    if(is_mobile)
        {

            $("#videoPlayer").removeClass('active');
            $("#thumbnail").addClass('hidePlayer');                     

        }

  }
  else
  {         
        ytplayer = new YT.Player('ytapiplayer', {
              height: '425',
              width: '356',
              videoId: id,
              suggestedQuality: 'hd720',
              playerVars: {'controls': youtube_control,'autoplay':1 },
              events: {
                'onReady': onYouTubePlayerReady
              }
        }); 

        if(start_youtube =="1")
        {
            $("#videoPlayer").addClass('active');
            $("#thumbnail").removeClass('hidePlayer');          
            $("#amazon").hide();
        }

        if(is_mobile)
        {

            $("#videoPlayer").addClass('active');
            $("#thumbnail").removeClass('hidePlayer');
            $('#thumbnailx ,.info-thumb').popover('show');
            setTimeout(function() {$('#thumbnailx ,.info-thumb').popover('hide');}, 5000);

        }

  }
}
```

and this is my `header`:

```
    <script src="//www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var base_url              = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
    var popup                 = '<?php echo $this->config->item("popup"); ?>';
    var is_mobile             = '<?php echo $this->agent->is_mobile(); ?>';
    var title                 = "<?php echo $this->config->item("title"); ?>"; 
    var label_loading         = "<?php echo ___('label_loading'); ?>";
    var extend                = "<?php echo $this->config->item('use_database'); ?>";
    var start_youtube         = "0";
    var label_loading_playlist= "<?php echo ___('label_loading_playlist'); ?>";
    var error_max             = "<?php echo ___('error_playlist_max'); ?>";
    var hide_ads_registered   = "<?php echo $this->config->item('hide_ads_registered'); ?>";
    var is_logged             = "<?php echo is_logged(); ?>";
    var youtube_control       = "<?php echo $this->config->item('youtube_controls'); ?>";
    var youtube_quality       = "<?php echo $this->config->item('youtube_quality'); ?>";
    </script>
```

I become crazy as I cannot find the problem, I don't have errors on my console.

How could I fix it?

Comment: Could you add a demo and/or some additional code to see the how the videos are loaded?

Comment: Also, your issue could be related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802498/youtube-iframe-api-setplaybackquality-or-suggestedquality-not-working/

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro finally I found the solution in your link! Thank you so much ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the user Alvaro Montoro, I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802498/youtube-iframe-api-setplaybackquality-or-suggestedquality-not-working/) the solution.

I added this function to the `custom.js`:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        event.target.setPlaybackQuality('hd720');  // <-- WORKS!
    }
}
```

in the same JavaScript I edit the `ytplayer`:

```
ytplayer = new YT.Player('ytapiplayer', {
              height: '100%',
              width: '100%',
              videoId: id,
              suggestedQuality: 'hd720',
              playerVars: {'controls': youtube_control,'autoplay':1 },
              events: {
                'onReady': onYouTubePlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
              }
        });
```

This will work ONLY if the player size is at least 720px in height.

Thanks to ALL of YOU