# What's the possible reason for YouTube dropdown quality to "default" using the JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I'm confusing and a bit frustrated, I don't know what's wrong but on my website when I play for the first time a video it's shown at my suggested quality "hd720", however when I click my API next video button, the quality of the video drop down to "default".

I already asked for some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605721/why-onclick-next-video-function-using-the-youtube-javascript-player-api-the-qu), but on this new question I wanna simply know what are possible reasons for that.

How can I check what's wrong if from console I have no errors?

Comment: Please don't ask a duplicate questions. If you wish to highlight an existing question [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) or edit to include more detail.

Comment: @Liam thanks, but here I'm asking for a different thing, How can I check what's wrong if from console I have no errors?...If you think, I'll close it

Comment: Ok fair enough. You should probably make this more clear in your question. If I were you I would simply edit the existing question though and potentially add a bounty too, your more likely to get good answers that way. It's already got upvotes and this question doesn't make sense without the attached one.

Comment: @Liam Thanks for suggestions, by the way do you know that my surname means "bear" in italian? :D

Comment: Prago. Non, parlo un po italian!! Picolino!