# Stop multiple WebBrowsers from starting yt-videos?

Tags: c#, html, winforms, youtube, webbrowser-control

I'm working with a **winform** `TabControl` showing `WebBrowser`controls to display youtube videos.
However with two videos or more it becomes really annoying as all videos start directly.

**I basically need to find out if there is a JS function, html code or a simple `WebBrowser` property to change, so videos are paused.**

***It might come in handy to find something like that for video quality too.***

Has anybody ever heard of/seen where this option is stored? Or maybe the Js function itself being invoked when manually setting the quality?

**EDIT:**

```
b.DocumentCompleted += delegate { b.DocumentText=b.DocumentText.Insert(b.DocumentText.IndexOf("class=\"video-stream html5-main-video\""), "autoplay=false ");};
b.Url = new System.Uri(inp[s], System.UriKind.Absolute);
```

Basically this should add a new Event handler on each webbrowser form that modifies the `DocumentText` when the Uri that is called during creation has loaded.

Even though the browser debugger shows

```
<video tabindex="-1" class="video-stream html5-main-video" controlslist="nodownload" style=... src=...></video>
```

this isn't in the actual source code.
However I found

```
$oa=function(a){g.S(a.o,"video-stream");g.S(a.o,"html5-main-video");var b=a.app.g;b.zc&&a.o.setAttribute("data-no-fullscreen",!0);b.Oh&&(a.o.setAttribute("webkit-playsinline",""),a.o.setAttribute("playsinline",""));b.Nr&&a.o&&a.P(a.o,"click",a.o.play,a.o)};
```

in the `base.js`. Is it possible that youtube generates the html from the js?
How can I modify the video-tag attributes then?

I tried to modify when the event handler manipulates the video tag, since there may be `DocumentCompleted` events thrown from scripts or anything.

```
delegate (object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e){
    if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != ((System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser)sender).Url.AbsolutePath){
        //...
```

However it still fails as there is no occurance of the specific class that on the video tag.

---

**I now dodged this by loading the Url only when the browser tab is selected, if someone finds a real solution, feel free to share**

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802498/youtube-iframe-api-setplaybackquality-or-suggestedquality-not-working

Comment: Well that shows that the API is capable of setting the quality. But I don't see how that should be a duplicate. Apart from my edit I'm not even talking about the API, since it is only my plan b if nothing else(finding settings in the storage or the JS functions) will work.